# How can I create an Access instance with VBA and leave it open?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

Here's a piece of vbs code that creates an Access database.

```
option explicit

dim accessFile
dim acc
dim fso

accessFile = "c:\users\rene.nyffenegger\documents\tq84.accdb"

set fso = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if fso.fileExists(accessFile) then
   fso.deleteFile(accessFile)
end if

set acc = createObject("Access.Application")

acc.newCurrentDatabase accessFile, 0

acc.visible = True
```

When started on the command line (`u:\> createDB.vbs`), the Access database is created. Yet, when the script exits the Access application is closed as well. I'd rather have the application stay open after creation. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the Application's [UserControl property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836033.aspx) to True.

```
Set acc = CreateObject("Access.Application")
acc.NewCurrentDatabase accessFile, 0
acc.Visible = True
acc.UserControl = True
```